# Insert separator only if didn’t insert one before

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a template variable `product_list`, which is a `QuerySet` of `Product` objects; `Product` objects, in turn, have a one-to-many field of `Track` objects (reverse mapped from `Track`, of course), which is possible to be empty. I want to create a list of `Track`s, grouped by `Product`s like this:

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    {% if this is not the first product with tracks %}
        <li class="separator"></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for track in product.tracks %}
        <li>{{track}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The question is, what should I write of `if this is not the first product with tracks`? I tried `ifchanged  product` but it inserts a separator even on the first iteration (as it changes from `""` to `"someproduct"`). `forloop.counter` is also not usable here, as it is possible that the first two products won’t have tracks.

One workaround could be to change `product_list` to `track_list` like this:

```
track_list = Track.objects.order_by('product__name')
```

so I can indeed use `ifchanged`. It is doable in my case, but I’m still interested in a solution for my first method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compose the condition. It looks simple, perhaps is not this that your are asking for.

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    {% if not forloop.first and product.tracks %}
        <li class="separator"></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for track in product.tracks %}
        <li>{{track}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If this is not a solution for you, I suggest to you to **cook data on view and send ready to be parse to template**, more easy.

```
{% for product in product_list %}
    {% if product.should_have_separator %}
        <li class="separator"></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for track in product.tracks %}
        <li>{{track}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In your view append `should_have_separator` field dynamically to products should have it:

```
product_list = Product.objects.....
is_the_first_product = True
for product in product_list:
    is_the_first_product_with_tracks = ( is_the_first_product 
                                        and bool( product.tracks ) )
    product.should_have_separator = not is_the_first_product_with_tracks
    is_the_first_product = False
```

Comment: It's not a view but a template context processor that adds the variable, but yes, it's the cooking method that won. I'm still measuring if this is fast enough during high load, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Sorry, I was on holiday. I took the second approach, pre-cooking my data; it seems that this problem is not solvable purely with template logic.

Comment: Forgot to add my cooking method (in the view or the context processor): `product_list.filter(tracks__isnull=False).distinct()`. `distinct()` is needed because without that products will be in the QuerySet as <track count> times.